# Increment an int each time Toast show something

Tags: java, android

I want to when the Toast shows message "Correct!", the TextView show score value on itself and for next times score be increment by 1. It works for first time that Toast show the message (TextView will show 1), but for second time and beyond does not work. Is that possible anyway?

```
int messageAnswer;
int score = 0;
if (condition is true) {
     messageAnswer = R.string.correct_toast;
     score++;
     scoreText.setText(String.valueOf(score));
} else {
     messageAnswer = R.string.incorrect_toast;
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messageAnswer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you enter this block of code, `score` is newly created and initialized with 0. You need to define it outside of this block, e.g. as an instance variable `private int score = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that `score` is a local variable.

It is reset to 0 every time the function to check the answer and display the `Toast` is called.

You need to make it an instance variable, a field in whatever class this code is in, so that it retains its value between function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You set `score = 0` just before calling the toast, each time you call the toast. It should be initialized only once. You should move it upper in your program, outside the loop or however you come back here.